# Azure ClearDB - Not taking database name

Tags: azure, cleardb

I'm creating a new ClearDB database in the Azure portal, the portal creates the database but using what appears to be an auto-generated name using the convention 'acsm_somehexchars'.  The database I'm trying to create is in a resource group which is empty and I really need the database name to be predictable.  I have tried creating a new resource group but still get the same behavior.

Any recommendations on how to be able to create a ClearDB with a predictable name whether than be changing the name of an existing ClearDB in Azure post deployment or doing it on startup would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the new portal (https://portal.azure.com), you should be able to choose the name of your Database during creation time.

[image]

The hostname is automaticaly generated (in the Shared Database type) but you can choose the Database name.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is an option to 'Manage Database' which takes you to the ClearDB website, in there it listed a database titled the same name I was trying to set it to, the interesting thing being the Azure portal and the ClearDB portal didn't match each other.

I have since deleted the database from the ClearDb portal and tried again however after making the ClearDB portal match the Azure portal by manually deleting databases in the ClearDB.

Answer (score 0):

I received an email from ClearDB Team said

> Thank you for creating a new ClearDB database. During the creation process, 
>   we found that the database name that you specified was already reserved, and 
>   although it passed the validation check in Windows Azure, we could not create a 
>   database using the same name in our systems.
>
> Instead, our systems have automatically assigned a globally unique database name 
>   for your database so that it may be created, and assigned a service name alias to 
>   it so that you may locate it within the Windows Azure portal. The following 
>   information represents how your database appears in both our systems as well 
>   as within Windows Azure:
>
> Actual database name: acsm_2aa7d07b8dba5d8 (this is what you'll see in the ClearDB console)
>
> Service name alias: exam (this is what you'll see in Windows Azure)

So maybe you need to use a different database name :)